# Compiling JZMQ on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, zeromq, jzmq

Hello all I'm attempting to follow the directions located at: https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Installing-native-dependencies for installing Zero MQ as a dependency for Storm on a Ubuntu 12.04 machine. However when trying to run the make command I get the following error

```
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/localadmin/jzmq/src'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `classdist_noinst.stamp', needed by `org/zeromq/ZMQ.class'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/localadmin/jzmq/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Does anyone have any idea where this error stems from and how I would be able to correct it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Apparently compiling JZMQ on Ubuntu 12.04 is a little bit more involved than I realized. However I took the time to write out the solution that I found. You can find it at: [Installing Storm's Native Dependencies on Ubuntu 12.04](http://www.christophermaness.com/installing-storms-native-dependencies-on-ubuntu-1204).
 For time's sake here are the instructions:

1. You’ll need to ensure that a few packages are installed first: build-essential, uuid-dev, libtool, git, autoconf, openjdk-6-jdk
2. Create a JAVA_HOME variable that point the the jdk you just installed. Should be in the /usr/lib/jvm directory

   `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/(your jdk folder); export JAVA_HOME`
3. Run the following commands for installing Zero MQ:

   ```
   wget http://download.zeromq.org/zeromq-2.1.7.tar.gz
   tar -xzf zeromq-2.1.7.tar.gz
   cd zeromq-2.1.7
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   ```
4. Download JZMQ and navigate to the the src directory

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/nathanmarz/jzmq.git
   cd jzmq
   cd src
   ```
5. Once in the src directory run the touch command to create a file and then redefine the classpath.

   ```
   touch classdist_noinst.stamp
   CLASSPATH=.:./.:$CLASSPATH javac -d . org/zeromq/ZMQ.java org/zeromq/ZMQException.java org/zeromq/ZMQQueue.java org/zeromq/ZMQForwarder.java org/zeromq/ZMQStreamer.java
   ```

   6.Navigate back to the /jzmq and run make

   ```
   cd ..
   ./autogen.sh 
   If you get this error "autogen.sh: error: could not find pkg-config.pkg-config is required to run autogen.sh", then install pkg-config. In Ubuntu sudo apt-get install pkg-config and again run the above command.
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

Parts of this were stitched together from the [Storm - Installing Native Dependencies](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Installing-native-dependencies) and [Tijun - How to build jzmq in Mac OS X Lion](http://tjun.jp/blog/2012/04/how-to-build-jzmq-in-mac-os-x-lion/). Thanks guys for putting your pieces of the puzzle up I just stitched them together.

Comment: Thanks, this was super helpful for JZMQ on ubuntu 13.10. One thing that I couldn't get to work and had to edit 'jzmq-master/configure' is to add 'export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64' after installing openjdk-6-jdk and setting env variable.

Answer (score 6):

There is a fix for this now in the zeromq/jzmq repo that I added to the my frozen jzmq repo: https://github.com/halfaleague/jzmq

Now, you can just follow the directions (`./autogen.sh`, `./configure`, `make`, `make install`).

Comment: Hey thanks for doing this I'm sure users everywhere will really appreciate this.

Comment: When using your repository to compile jzmq on Mac OS X 10.8.3 with Java 1.7.0_25 I saw errors like `error: jni_md.h: No such file or directory ... error: 'JNIEXPORT' does not name a type`. To fix that I had to add the following line after line 108 in `configure.in`: `CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/darwin"` . Only then I was able to compile the code.

Comment: For compiling jzmq on Mac OS X use this repository https://github.com/asmaier/jzmq . It includes my fix mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use the package manager to install it?

```
sudo apt-get install libzmq0 libzmq-dev zeromq-bin
```

Comment: I am getting this: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libzmq0
E: Unable to locate package zeromq-bin

Comment: @SazzadHossainKhan - As this post was 2 years ago, you will probably need to use a newer lib: `apt-cache search libzmq`

Comment: This is a bad idea since Storm requires a specific version of ZeroMQ (2.1.7 at the time of writing), which may not be provided by the package manager.

Answer (score 4):

You need to replace `classdist_noinst.stamp` with `classnoinst.stamp` in `jzmq/src/**Makefile.am**`

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring), I needed to run the following before the ./autogen.sh step:

> > sed -i 's/classdist_noinst.stamp/classnoinst.stamp/g' src/Makefile.am

I found this workaround here, and I think that this thread could be useful to anyone with that kind of problems: https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq/issues/114