# Storm workers not starting

Tags: java, ubuntu-12.04, zeromq, apache-storm, jzmq

My Nimbus host and supervisor run properly. When I submit a wordcount topology to the Nimbus host it successfully upload. After uploading topology supervisor giving error

```
kill: No such process
```

When I check the `worker-6001.log` and `6002.log` I found a following error:

```
2014-02-09 17:20:05 b.s.m.TransportFactory [INFO] Storm peer transport     plugin:backtype.storm.messaging.zmq
2014-02-09 17:20:05 b.s.d.worker [ERROR] Error on initialization of server mk-worker
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jzmq in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at org.zeromq.ZMQ.<clinit>(ZMQ.java:34) ~[jzmq-2.1.0.jar:na]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at backtype.storm.messaging.zmq$loading__4784__auto__.invoke(zmq.clj:1) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.messaging.zmq__init.load(Unknown Source) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.messaging.zmq__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2056) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:400) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
at clojure.core$load$fn__4890.invoke(core.clj:5415) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5414) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:415) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.messaging.zmq.<clinit>(Unknown Source) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at backtype.storm.messaging.TransportFactory.makeContext(TransportFactory.java:21) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$worker_data$fn__5732.invoke(worker.clj:170) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.util$assoc_apply_self.invoke(util.clj:761) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$worker_data.invoke(worker.clj:166) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__5882$exec_fn__1229__auto____5883.invoke(worker.clj:338) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:185) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:601) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__5882$mk_worker__5938.doInvoke(worker.clj:329)     [storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$_main.invoke(worker.clj:439) [storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:172) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.daemon.worker.main(Unknown Source) [storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
2014-02-09 17:20:05 b.s.util [INFO] Halting process: ("Error on initialization")
```

my configuration is

storm.yaml

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
 - "192.168.1.2"

storm.local.dir: "/usr/local/storm/data"
java.library.path: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/lib"

nimbus.host: "192.168.1.2"
nimbus.task.launch.secs: 240
supervisor.worker.start.timeout.secs: 240
supervisor.worker.timeout.secs: 240  
supervisor.slots.ports:
- 6700
- 6701
```

java version

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.4) (7u51-2.4.4-0ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

I used [this blog](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2013/11/InstallingAndConfiguringStormOnUbuntu.html) as a example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The resolution depends on the version of Storm you're running.

---

[EDIT]

Storm 0.9.1 has just been released today (22nd Feb 2014): release notes mention zeroMQ dependencies are now by default replaced by Netty

https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=incubator-storm.git;a=blob_plain;f=CHANGELOG.md;hb=254ec135b9a67b1e7bc8e979356274aee2e7d715

---

The installation instructions of the previous version (I successfully used those for 0.8.2 in the past) are here, they indeed mention zeroMq and jzmq as dependencies:

https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Setting-up-a-Storm-cluster

The installation instructions of 0.9.0.1 are here: they do not mention zeroMQ nor jzmq:

http://storm.incubator.apache.org/documentation/Setting-up-a-Storm-cluster.html

According to the release notes of Storm 0.9.0, we now have the choice between Netty and ZeroMQ for tuple transport, so in theory you should be able to solve this issue by upgrading to 0.9.0.1, not install zeroMQ nor jzmq and configure storm as mentioned here:

(dawn, not allowed to post a 3rd link, ok, the release notes are on the Storm blog, in the Storm incubator apache web site ^__^)

--
Svend

Comment: Storm 0.9.0 release notes: 
http://storm.incubator.apache.org/2013/12/08/storm090-released.html

Comment: can you help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612810/exception-after-submitting-topology?noredirect=1#comment53179266_32612810

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, jzmq is missing. Make sure that jzmq was built **successfully** on all your machines. Make sure also that jzmq is under **java.library.path**.

And by the way, the file is **storm.yaml** not **Storm.yaml**

Check this question on how to [Compiling JZMQ on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115160/compiling-jzmq-on-ubuntu).