# JAVA_HOME NOT SET WHEN INSTALL Storm

Tags: streaming, apache-storm, java-home, jzmq

I want to install Storm in my own machine(Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) and I follow the instructions in

```
    https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Installing-native-dependencies.
```

When I installing jzmq, I firstly successfully perform the command

```
    sudo ./autogen.sh
```

however, when I perform

```
    sudo ./configure
```

The configuration error:

```
    'configure: error: the JAVA_HOME environment variable must be set to your JDK location.'
```

appears.

I have set the JAVA_HOME using

```
    sudo gedit /etc/profile
    export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_35
    export JRE_HOME=.....
    export CLASSPATH=......
    source /etc/profile
```

and the output of

```
    echo $JAVA_HOME
```

is

```
    '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_35'.
```

I do not know why the error happens, anyone knows it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should move the answer into an answer rather than edit the question and fill it in. This way it's clear to other SO users that this question has an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Hit the same issue among others while installing JZMQ as part of Storm 0.82 install a couple of months back. Solved this problem by doing exactly what you outlined above. There were some other gotchas for JZMQ. Copying my INSTALL steps and hopefully they'll be useful.

```
NOTE: OPENJDK 6 Required! 
- sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
- export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64
- MUST READ: 
  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115160/compiling-jzmq-on-ubuntu
  - https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Installing-native-dependencies
- wget https://github.com/nathanmarz/jzmq/archive/master.zip
- cd /usr/local/
  - sudo unzip jzmq-master.zip (OR master.zip)
  - cd jzmq-master
  - INSTALL:
    - Potentially Missing Pre-req:
      - libtool: sudo apt-get install libtool
      - autoconf: sudo apt-get install autoconf
      - (automake was already installed)
    - sudo ./autogen.sh
    - **Edit ./configure file to add "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64"**
    - sudo ./configure
    - cd src
    - sudo touch classdist_noinst.stamp
    - sudo CLASSPATH=.:./.:$CLASSPATH javac -d . org/zeromq/ZMQ.java org/zeromq/ZMQException.java org/zeromq/ZMQQueue.java org/zeromq/ZMQForwarder.java org/zeromq/ZMQStreamer.java
    - cd ..
    - sudo make
    - sudo make install
```

Answer (score 2):

***###############################################################################***
***Here I give my way to solve the problem:***

1. Open configure in jzmq folder

   ```
   sudo gedit configure
   ```
2. Find codes bellow:

   ```
   # Check for JDK
   if test "x$JAVA_HOME" = "x"; then
       as_fn_error $? "the JAVA_HOME environment variable must be set to your JDK location." "$LINENO" 5;
   fi
   ```
3. set JAVA_HOME here:

   ```
   # Check for JDK
   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jdk1.6.0_35
   echo $JAVA_HOME
   if test "x$JAVA_HOME" = "x"; then
       as_fn_error $? "the JAVA_HOME environment variable must be set to your JDK location." "$LINENO" 5;
   fi
   ```
4. This method can solve my problem, maybe it is useful for you.