# cannot find jni.h in /usr/lib/

Tags: java, apache-storm, jzmq

I'm using Ubuntu and trying to install storm but got this

```
checking for jni.h in /usr/lib/jdk1.6.0_36/include... configure: error: cannot find jni.h in /usr/lib/jdk1.6.0_36/include.
```

when used this command

```
./configure
```

in `JZMQ` installation

```
java -version 

java version "1.6.0_36"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.8) (6b36-1.13.8-0ubuntu1~14.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

i tried to edit in `configure` by used

```
sudo gedit configure
```

but same problem

tried to edit `bashrc` i added this line at the end of the file

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/
```

but problem still

openjdk is in this path `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64`

any solution ? why i got this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least you should have `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64` if you want to use this openjdk distribution.

Finally your configure/make should try to find jni.h in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/include`
So, if you have an access to this property for "configure" - you can just change it to this value (of course, check before that file by this path actually exists)

Finally during "make" phase this path should be used this way:

```
gcc -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/include ...
```

Comment: i tried it but got error the JAVA_HOME environment variable must be set to your JDK location

Comment: Looks like it's another issue and can be fixed [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22245150/525203). Try?